# Extract value statement using XML

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

Trying to extract a value from XML and put it in a column named "site id".

I keep getting an error saying "invalid relational operator" after I close the parentheses. I don't have specific site id I am looking for, just want to get all the site ids to load to a separate column. Not sure if this is possible.

```
select * from ord_activity_cust_data
  where extractValue(activity_data, '/A02_EFOPRM/SiteId',
        'xmlns="http://www.ventyx.com/ServiceSuite"')
  as 'Site ID';
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
select extractValue(activity_data,'/A02_EFOPRM/SiteId','xmlns="http://www.ventyx.com/ServiceSuite"') as "Site ID" 
from ord_activity_cust_data
   ;
```